# What does it say on my Japanese alarm clock?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, culture

I bought an alarm clock (good clocks with AA batteries instead of button-like) with Japanese characters and found it difficult to understand, even with a dictionary. Could someone explain what is written on my alarm clock?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just for extra info, if you have a smartphone, you can use the Google Translate App (for iOS or Android) to take a [clear] photo of anything with foreign characters (including Japanese!) and translate the input photo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is all you need.

- 午前 AM ・ 午後 PM
- 日 SUN ・ 月 MON ・ 火 TUE ・ 水 WED ・ 木 THU ・ 金 FRI ・ 土 SAT
- 先勝 *sensh­ō* ・ 友引 *tomobiki*/*y­ūin* ・ 先負 *senbu* ・ 仏滅 *butsumetsu* ・ 大安 *taian*/*daian* ・ 赤口 *shakkō* ¹
- モニター display
- 時刻合わせ sync
- リセット reset
- 戻る back
- 進む forward
- アラーム alarm

---

¹ six-day cycle of auspicious/inauspicious days. More info [here](http://www.seiyaku.com/customs/rokuyo-about.html#days) or on [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E6%9B%9C).